# Product Salable Quantity default 0(zero) when create new product in magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2

In magento 2.3.1 when we create new product & set it's quantity 100; but automatically save Product Salable Quantity 0(zero) when we save this product.
Why Product Salable Quantity not set as per add product quantity.
Else why not change it from admin side.
Changes in database is not possible from site owner.
Any one help me for solve both points

Comment: Check and READ this ;) https://www.reachdigital.nl/en/blog/magento-msi-multi-source-inventory-features